# Using find vs. get in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, query-builder, cakephp-3.0

There were some functions in one of my controllers that I cleaned up in this manner:

Old function:

```
return $this->find()
    ->where(['id' => $id])
    ->first();
```

New:

```
return $this->get($id);
```

Which is faster, or which is preferred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be virtually no difference with regards to performance, just look at the source code, and/or simply test it. On `1000` iterations I can see a difference of `0.0001` seconds, that's nothing one should need to worry about.

The additional processing that is needed to build the query should be absolutely minimal once [**the primary key and the alias**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/5e996cd4b90fd31dd71c12a3be04e4c851b8c6ae/src/ORM/Table.php#L914-L915) are "cached" (wich by default should happen when the table class is [**instantiated**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/b08711064acda6ab83c294366d7d40f400cbe3ef/src/ORM/TableRegistry.php#L170), respectively [**initialized**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/5e996cd4b90fd31dd71c12a3be04e4c851b8c6ae/src/ORM/Table.php#L259) when baked).

At that point the pretty much only difference should then be that `get()` is shorter and [**throws an exception**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/5e996cd4b90fd31dd71c12a3be04e4c851b8c6ae/src/ORM/Table.php#L950) when the record isn't found.

See also **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#loading-entities**

Comment: @relinquish: To sum it up: use `get()` when you know the ID, expect it to exist and search by exactly that (e.g. edit forms, view ctp), otherwise use `find()`. It is as simple as that (and also kind of explains itself if you think about it).